# Adding a column in data.table with looking up a value in another data.table (based on TWO similar columns)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a question regarding adding a column to a data.table based on info in another data.table.

This is how my data looks:

Datatable 1 (football matches)

```
 TeamcodeHome TeamcodeAway GoalsHome GoalsAway Season
 1            2            5         0         2006
```

Datatable 2 (cards received by football teams):

```
Teamcode Season Red Yellow
1        2005   1   15
2        2005   3   10
1        2006   4   16
2        2006   1   4
```

Now I would use the following function in datatable if I want to add a column based on 1 other column:

```
dt.1[dt.2, on="Teamcode", RedCards:=Red]
```

But now there are two variables that need to be matched. Teamcode and Season. How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

The help page `?data.table` says about the `on` parameter:

> Indicate which columns in `i` should be joined with columns in `x` along
>   with the type of binary operator to join with. When specified, this
>   overrides the keys set on `x` and `i`. There are multiple ways of
>   specifying on argument:
>
> - As a character vector, e.g., `X[Y, on=c("a", "b")]`. This assumes both these columns are present in `X` and `Y`.
> - As a named character vector, e.g., `X[Y, on=c(x="a", y="b")]`. This is useful when column names to join by are different between the two
>     tables.
>     NB: `X[Y, on=c("a", y="b")]` is also possible if column `"a"` is
>     common between the two tables.
> - For convenience during interactive scenarios, it is also possible to use `.()` syntax as `X[Y, on=.(a, b)]`.

(It also recommends the vignette [Secondary indices and auto indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html).)

So, this would be a possible join on two columns:

```
dt.1[dt.2, on = .(TeamcodeHome = Teamcode, Season), RedCardsHome := Red][]
```

> ```
>    TeamcodeHome TeamcodeAway GoalsHome GoalsAway Season RedCardsHome
> 1:            1            2         5         0   2006            4
> ```